# Terminar un programa C# con while infinito

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio, while

me encuentro realizando un trabajo de la uni y me encuentro con un pequeño error el cual es que al momento de imprimir mis resultados no se acaba el programa, si no se repite y se repite la condicion, ya trate de usar Console.ReadKey pero no me ha solucionado nada, alguna ayuda?

Me parece ser que el error se encuentra desde que introduzco los valores menores a 600 y mayores a 200, pero supongo que con un break se deberia de acabar, pero no es asi, llevo poco tiempo programando asi que si es un error de logica les pido perdon jeje, adjunto mi codigo:

EDIT:
Parece ser que esta funcion es infinita, en este caso como logro terminar con el programa?

```
            while (tam <= 16 && tam > 0)
            {
                int[,] matriz = new int[renglon, columna];
                for (int i = 0; i < renglon; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++)
            //Ingreso de datos por el usuario 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Introduce numeros menores a 600 y mayores a 200:");
                        matriz[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Si los datos ingresados por el usuario son correctos empieza el arreglo de conjetura de Collatz 
                        while (matriz[i, j] >= 200 && matriz[i, j] <= 600)
                        {
                            numero = matriz[i, j];
                            //Contador de pasos
                            con = 0;
                            //Conjetura de collatz
                            while (numero != 1)
                            {
                                if (numero % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    numero = (numero / 2);//Si el numero es par se divide entre dos
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    numero= numero * 3 + 1;//Si el numero es non se multiplica por 3
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine(numero);
                                con++;
                            }
                            //Salida de cuantos pasos se hicieron para llegar al numero 1
                            Console.WriteLine("Total de pasos: "+" pasos" + con);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta condicion es eterna para ciertos numeros: matriz[i, j] >= 200 && matriz[i, j] <= 600

Comment: @gbianchi Pero si quiero que acabe la condicion cuando acabe el programa, con un simple break bastaría, lo acabo de intentar y no soluciona el error. :/

Comment: un break va a cortar el while del nivel que estes.. tenes 2 for y 2 while todos anidados... no se donde queres meter el break...

Comment: tal vez un return? igual toda la logica de tu codigo es rara...

Comment: Listo, la solucion fue el return no lo habia pensado, pero si igual la logica que emplee me quebre la cabeza jaja y ademas hice que funcionara, en fin muchas gracias por ayudar, Saludos!